# Yarn can not connect to namenode cluster

Tags: hdfs, hadoop-yarn, cloudera

2018-03-08 16:36:16,775 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService: Downloading public rsrc:{ hdfs://mycluster/user/abc_user/udf/pig_udf-1.5.7_handle_input_error.jar, 1516336589685, FILE, null }
2018-03-08 16:36:16,775 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService: Failed to download resource { { hdfs://mycluster/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20171215093741/pig/libgplcompression.so.0.0.0, 1513307849411, FILE, null },pending,[(container_1519371600813_0002_02_000001)],8140205165392614,DOWNLOADING}
**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: mycluster**
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.buildTokenService(SecurityUtil.java:406)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createNonHAProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:310)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:176)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.(DFSClient.java:728)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.(DFSClient.java:671)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:155)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2815)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:98)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2852)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2834)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:387)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.copy(FSDownload.java:249)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:356)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:60)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecumytor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mycluster

Yarn-nodemanager service and Data-node service is on the same machine

Yarn-resource-manager service and NameNode in on the same machine

When run a simple pig script load data and print . I met above error .

Before add standby Namnode everything work well.

How can I config yarn to understand my NameNode Cluster

Thanks you

Comment: _"add standby Namnode"_ > you mean you set up HDFS High Availability?? Did you restart YARN services since then? Did you test that the client config relects that change on all cluster nodes? And did you make sure that YARN services use the same config files as the clients ?

Answer (score 0):

After check again hdfs-site.xml on 2 DataNode where Yarn Node Manager stand on , I see that the hdfs-site file missing this line when compare with the hdfs-site on Name Node

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.client.failover.proxy.provider.mycluster</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider</value>
</property>
```

It working now